# How to view cloudfoundry logs when cf login fail

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have used bosh-lite to deploy a single node cloudfoundry in my development environment. After deployment, I run the bosh vms, and it returns the vms list:

```
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+

| Job/index                          | State   | Resource Pool | IPs          |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+

| api_z1/0                           | running | large_z1      | 10.244.0.138 |

| etcd_leader_z1/0                   | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.38  |

| ha_proxy_z1/0                      | running | router_z1     | 10.244.0.34  |

| hm9000_z1/0                        | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.142 |

| loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0 | running | small_z1      | 10.244.0.10  |

| loggregator_z1/0                   | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.14  |

| login_z1/0                         | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.134 |

| nats_z1/0                          | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.6   |

| postgres_z1/0                      | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.30  |

| router_z1/0                        | running | router_z1     | 10.244.0.22  |

| runner_z1/0                        | running | runner_z1     | 10.244.0.26  |

| uaa_z1/0                           | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.130 |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
```

But when I try to use "cf api https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io --skip-ssl-validation" to connect the cloudfoundry, it returns an error:

> ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it.

The log information is very general (actually this is the exception from CF client which is written in .net), and doesn't provide useful information.

My question is, which VM handles the api command? And, where can I find the detail log in that VM?

Answer (score 0):

`api_z1/0` is handling the command.  You can get its logs via the BOSH CLI itself: `bosh logs api_z1 0 --all`.

You probably also need to add the route to your local route table so that traffic to HAProxy container at `10.244.0.24` knows to go through the BOSH-lite VM at `192.168.50.4`.  Run `bin/add-route` or `bin/add-route.bat` from the root of your BOSH-lite repo.